# Find the Smallest Value from these given digits

Tags: mathematics

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
+ - : x =

Find the smallest value from these following numbers and equations.
Each number and equations must be used once.

You can make it like ...:(-1)

Goodluck!

Comment: What operation is : in this instance, do you mean / or divide?

Comment: By "equations", do you mean operators? And what are we supposed to do with the = symbol?

Comment: Where are the equations? And can we use unknowns?

Comment: There are 10 numbers but only 5 so-called operators, so how can all the numbers be used without using them in combinations such as $987$?

Comment: Can we divide by zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'll give it a try. I see there's some downvotes, so I'll assume each operator can only be used once and thus the digits will have to be concatenated. Also the subtraction operator can be used as negation, judging by the example given. So my solution is:

> -84,396,426

Achieved by:

> (9642*8753+0)/(-1) = -84,396,426

Comment: you have a typo in your solution - you meant the second digit 4 should actually be 5. Also your solution can be improved by a factor of 10 if you use + not as a sum, but just as a positive.

Comment: @ppgdev yes, that was a typo, I've fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Improving @Amorydai answer based on my comment

> $(+9642)*(-87530)/1 = -843964260 $